# Facebook FBJS UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime, parsing, facebook, fbjs

I am pulling in data from a JSON file using FBJS AJAX. On of the values in the json file is a date. The date has a UTC format, `Date(1255535021000-0600)`.

However, I am getting an "invalid date" or "NaN" error whatever I do.

I have tried the following: `new Date(1255535021000-0600)`, `new Date(1255535021000)`, `Date.parse(1255535021000-0600)`, `Date.parse(1255535021000)`.

In old fashioned Javascript it works perfectly, but not when using FBJS.

What do I do to transform this into a usable date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around FBJS terrible parsing and lackluster constructor I created an empty Date() and then called setTime().

```
var tmp = new Date();
tmp.setTime(1255535021000);
```

This is a workable solution for now. However, I think that Facebook should do a better job providing consistent environment for the objects, like Date, that are, at least superficially, regular javascript.